# Kafka authentication mechanism

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=abcd
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=abcd
ssl.key.password=abcd
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="someuser" password="someuserspassword";
```

This is our kafka connection param. I am trying to make sense out of it

1. I assume this is using mutualTLS
   (For client to identify the server as the real server and also for server to authenticate the client) is that right assumption?
2. What is the transportation mechanism, is it plain text or TLS encrypted ? (sasl.mechanism=PLAIN confuses me) ?
3. Whats the role of username="someuser" password="someuserspassword" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume this is using mutualTLS (For client to identify the server as the real server and also for server to authenticate the client) is that right assumption?

Yesno. You configure a key in a keystore for client authentication, but that will only be used if the server indicates that it is required for the connection. After all, it is the server that would require client authentication.

> What is the transportation mechanism, is it plain text or TLS encrypted ? (sasl.mechanism=PLAIN confuses me)?

It is TLS protected. PLAIN is about the type of password mechanism that is used *over the established connection*, in this case PLAIN HTTP instead of e.g. a hashed password or another secure scheme. Such a scheme is not required precisely **because** TLS is established.

Beware that by default all supported *cipher suites* will be enabled, and the server will indicate which ones are preferred from the ones offered by the client. It is possible to narrow this down to `ssl.cipher.suites`, and if you have a security policy that requires it, you might want to do that if you don't want to be at the mercy of the server.

> Whats the role of username="someuser" password="someuserspassword" ?

It is indicated that [plain JAAS authentication](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html#kafka-sasl-auth) must be used **over** TLS, using those credentials, which, undoubtedly, you have to change.

*Beware that I'm a security professional that understands TLS and authentication options. I'm not a Kafka expert.*

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to clear the above points:

1. No, SASL_SSL is a process of client authentication over SSL/TLS communication with the help of the PLAIN authentication method supported by the Kafka. For both side certification, you need to set:

> ssl.client.auth=required.

2. It is not plain text, it is TLS encrypted. SASL/PLAIN with TLS/SSL ensures that clear passwords are not transmitted over transport layer without encryption.
3. In the Kafka server section, the username and the password are used by the broker to initiate connections to other brokers using PLAIN authentication method.